# Multiple plotly pie charts in one row

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotly

I am trying to arrange two pie charts in a single row using the `subplot` function from the plotly package but the resultant plot is not what I expect. I was able to do the same for line charts, etc but I am facing trouble plotting two pie charts in a single row. Following is the code that I have.

```
ds_r <- data.frame(labels = c("Baseline", "DTC", "Detailing", "Flex"),
                 values = c(63.5, 8.5, 20.6, 7.4))

ds_l <- data.frame(labels = c("Baseline"),
                 values = c(100))

plot_right <- plot_ly(ds_r, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie") %>% 
  layout(title = "Sales - Decomposed")

plot_left <- plot_ly(ds_l, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie") %>%
  layout(title = "Total Sales")

subplot(plot_left, plot_right, nrows = 2)
```

The output is

[image]

If you check the red boxes at the bottom of the image, there are two sets of axes which means there are two plots but they are probably getting overlapped or something.

I want the output to be two pie charts in a single row without any axes. Any help or direction?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plotly)
ds_r <- data.frame(labels1 = c("Baseline", "DTC", "Detailing", "Flex"),
                   values1 = c(63.5, 8.5, 20.6, 7.4))

ds_l <- data.frame(labels2 = c("Baseline"),
                   values2 = c(100))
df <- cbind(ds_r, ds_l)

plot_ly(df, labels = labels1, values = values1, type = "pie", 
        domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4)), showlegend = F) %>% 

  add_trace(labels = labels2, values = values2, type = "pie", 
            domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1)), showlegend = F)
```

I would add the picture, but plotlies are generally large files.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good approach. Will help me get ahead but isn't there a way to do this with subplot which I think is more staright forward and consistent

Comment: I do not believe so. I think subplots are mostly used for aligned line charts or scatter plots which are grouped according to the levels of some factor.

Answer (score 2):

There is new improved `subplot` functionality coming in the development version of `plotly`, but it appears the "bug" persists.  I am not sure though how well it works with pie charts.  I filed an [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/655) on Github.

```
# devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly")

library(plotly)
ds_r <- data.frame(labels1 = c("Baseline", "DTC", "Detailing", "Flex"),
                   values1 = c(63.5, 8.5, 20.6, 7.4))

ds_l <- data.frame(labels2 = c("Baseline"),
                   values2 = c(100))

p <- plot_ly(ds_r, labels = ~labels1, values = ~values1, type = "pie", 
           showlegend = F) 

p2 <- plot_ly(ds_l,labels = ~labels2, values = ~values2, type = "pie", 
           showlegend = F)

subplot(p, p2, nrows = 1)
```

For more detail on `subplot`, see the [subplot vignette](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/vignettes/subplot.Rmd).